# Container startup failing for testcontainers-scala

Tags: docker, scala, testcontainers

I was testing out a simple test function as below using the library provided MySql test container when the container startup failed

```
class Test extends FlatSpec with ForAllTestContainer {
  override val container = MySQLContainer()

  it should "temp" in {
    assert(1 == 1)
  }
}
```

The stack trace for the error is as shown below

```
Exception encountered when invoking run on a nested suite - Container startup failed
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:322)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:302)
    at com.dimafeng.testcontainers.SingleContainer.start(Container.scala:46)
    at com.dimafeng.testcontainers.ForAllTestContainer.run(ForAllTestContainer.scala:17)
    at com.dimafeng.testcontainers.ForAllTestContainer.run$(ForAllTestContainer.scala:13)
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageNameFuture=java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@18920cc[Completed normally], imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy(), dockerClient=LazyDockerClient.INSTANCE)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1265)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.logger(GenericContainer.java:600)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:311)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.start(ResourceReaper.java:103)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:155)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.listImagesCmd(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.maybeInitCache(LocalImagesCache.java:68)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.get(LocalImagesCache.java:32)
    at org.testcontainers.images.AbstractImagePullPolicy.shouldPull(AbstractImagePullPolicy.java:18)
    at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:62)
    at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:25)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.getResolvedValue(LazyFuture.java:20)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.get(LazyFuture.java:27)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1263)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: You probably need to specify a tag or something when creating the container. I would suggest opening an issue in their repo.

Comment: What version of Testcontainers are you using?